# calculating the limit of a 2 variable function

Tags: limits, 3d

The function is $$f(x,y) = \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}}}{x^4+y^4}$$
Prove (and calculate) / refute the Limit of the function where $x$ and $y$ go to $0
(x\rightarrow 0$ and $y\rightarrow 0)$

Comment: Is the edit correct?

Comment: You prove, calculate and refute, and let us be in peace.

Comment: yeah, how do u insert math equation? tried google it, couldnt find any simple solution

Comment: Better to write  $(x,y)\to (0,0).$

Comment: Do you know $\lim_{t\to 0} e^{-1/t^2}/t^4 = 0?$

Comment: yeah, however if we define x^2+y^2 = t^2, t^4 = x^4+y^4+2*x^2*y^2

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In polar coordinates we have

$$f(r\cos t, r\sin t) =\frac{e^{-1/r^2}}{r^4(\cos^4t + \sin^4 t)}.$$

Argue that the denominator above is $\ge r^4 c$ for some positive $c.$

Comment: I think you meant $e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}}$.

Comment: Yes I did, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let polar coordinates    $\\ x=r\cos { \theta  } \\ y=r\sin { \theta  } $ then we have $$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0,y\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { { e }^{ -\frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 } }  } }{ { x }^{ 4 }+{ y }^{ 4 } }  } =\lim _{ r\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { { e }^{ -\frac { 1 }{ { r }^{ 2 } }  } }{ { r }^{ 4 }\left( \cos ^{ 4 }{ \theta  } +\sin ^{ 4 }{ \theta  }  \right)  }  } =\frac { 1 }{ \left( \cos ^{ 4 }{ \theta  } +\sin ^{ 4 }{ \theta  }  \right)  } \lim _{ r\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { { e }^{ -\frac { 1 }{ { r }^{ 2 } }  } }{ { r }^{ 4 } }  } \\ \\ \\ $$

the last limit is equal to $0$ , you can observe it by the graphic of the function of $\frac { { e }^{ -\frac { 1 }{ { r }^{ 2 } }  } }{ { r }^{ 4 } } $ [image]